# My simple Form won't submit, to be used within PHP

Tags: php, html

I am writing a new PHP website, and have written a form, and the PHP code to handle the variables and the DB.

Trouble is, it won't even submit the form!  Usually when you submit, if you hit F5 it will ask if you want to 'send again', it doesn't even do that.  Something is clearly wrong, and I am a little rusty - but I thought I was ok with basic forms.

```php
<?php

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
echo "here: $username";

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="/signup2/" name="signuprocess">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

After submitting, the $username doesn't appear after "here:".
What I am doing that's a bit silly??

I have tried to post the code on here, but it sees it as spam, as it is a sign up form.

What can I post to show the code, without it being seen as such?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Indent the code 4 spaces or use the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Can you post your example code, so we can help you to see the problem?

Comment: <?php
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
echo "here: $username";
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;    
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>

<form method="post" action="/signup2/" name="signuprocess">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>

Comment: Here is an example. I stripped it right back and this won't post either.

Comment: Are you serving this code on the path "/signup2/"?

Comment: I tried your code without the `action="/signup2/"` attribute (so it would submit to itself). When I submit the form, the username totally shown up.

Answer (score 1):

When you "hit" F5 and the browser asks you to 'send again' is because you previously did a POST request. Otherwise, if your last request was, for example, a GET, the browser is not going to ask you anything. It will simply refresh the page.

try something like this

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'] ?? null;
echo "here: $username";
?>

<form method="post" action="" name="signuprocess">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is a POST request.

Comment: Do you need anything more from me to help?  This is just not posting, and I haven't the faintest idea why.

Comment: It's in an *.inc file, that's on a PHP website.  So it would be index.php?page-signup2.  I even stripped out the PHP, and ran it just as a POST, but the refresh still works... no "send again?"....

Comment: Adding a comment doesn't allow me to add all the code used.  But I'll do it in two chunks.  `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/source/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="sidemenu">
 <div class='menu-link'><a href='/login/'><i class='fas fa-angle-left'></i>login</a></div>
`

Comment: `<div class='menu-link'><a href='/signup/'><i class='fas fa-angle-left'></i>Create Account</a></div>
             </div>
<div class="pagebody">


<form method="post" action="/signup2/" name="signuprocess">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form></div>
<div style='clear: both'></div>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: I can use your plan, but if it it not even POSTing it, that won't work.  Something is stopping it.  Never comes across such a basic thing before.

Comment: Is the `action="/signup2/"` in the form right? Did you try with `action=""`?

Comment: Oooo if I change it to signup2.php, so it bypasses the index.php file, it works.  So it's something within my index.php file causing it...but I have no JS in there at all.

Comment: Oooo "" works without the 'signup2'... why would that be??

Comment: The problem is that `$_POST['username']` is null after submitting the form? Or what exactly?

Comment: There was no problem at all. If you go to the official docu for Forms: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html you will see how the attribute action works. It defines the URL where the form will be sent. So by don't specify anything, it will send everything to the current URL.

Comment: It's not actioning my code now, BUT it is performing the POST.   So if you are posting to it's own page, adding that page in the action, is wrong?  Very strange, but good to have found a fix.

Comment: no, it is not wrong. But then the form will send it data to that URL, which means you should have a path/file ready for that to receive that info. And there you will be able to get the `$_POST['username']` ;)

Comment: After it posts, it should be echoing that $username variable at the top.  but i just get a blank white screen.  It use to show PHP errors in Firefix or Chrome to warn of such issues.... is this for another thread??

Comment: yeah, better create another thread. And post the code example there. Otherwise, it will be hard for you to get some help ;)

Comment: Apologies, there error is there, it's just hidden.  My bad.